# ESXI How to view CPU usage

Tags: esxi

I am trying to get total CPU usage of the servers running the VMware ESXi 6.7.0 Update 3 to monitor performance.

I was able to view the memory usage using the command- vsish -e get /memory/comprehensive

However, I can't find a command for CPU usage. There isn't a top command or /proc/stat file.

Is there a way I can get this info?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I'm using ESXi 6.0.0U2 and after looking through the `vsish` nodes for a bit, I found some relevant information in the power/pcpu tree.

```
[root@server:~] vsish -e ls power
policy/
pcpu/
hardwareSupport
hostStats
resetStats
currentPolicy
```

```
[root@server:~] vsish -e ls power/pcpu
0/
1/
2/
3/
4/
5/
6/
7/
8/
9/
10/
11/
12/
13/
14/
15/
```

My server has 8 hyperthreaded CPUs, so 16 virtual cores show up in ESXi. Here's what it shows about the first core:

```
[root@server:~] vsish -e ls power/pcpu/0
cstate/
tstate/
pstate/
cres
perf
state
```

```
[root@server:~] vsish -e get power/pcpu/0/perf
PCPU performance statistics {
   PCPU core busy (current frequency): 40 %
   PCPU core busy (maximum frequency): 40 %
   APERF/MPERF ratio: -1 %
   Halted time: 176111536370 usec
}
```

Maybe there's a better way to do this, but this shows the info for all the cores:

```
[root@server:~] vsish -e get $(printf 'power/pcpu/%sperf ' $(vsish -e ls power/pcpu))
PCPU performance statistics {
   PCPU core busy (current frequency): 100 %
   PCPU core busy (maximum frequency): 100 %
   APERF/MPERF ratio: -1 %
   Halted time: 175721833728 usec
}
PCPU performance statistics {
   PCPU core busy (current frequency): 100 %
   PCPU core busy (maximum frequency): 100 %
   APERF/MPERF ratio: -1 %
   Halted time: 188174562097 usec
}
PCPU performance statistics {
   PCPU core busy (current frequency): 24 %
   PCPU core busy (maximum frequency): 24 %
   APERF/MPERF ratio: -1 %
   Halted time: 174102490208 usec
}
PCPU performance statistics {
   PCPU core busy (current frequency): 20 %
   PCPU core busy (maximum frequency): 20 %
   APERF/MPERF ratio: -1 %
   Halted time: 187428554783 usec
}
PCPU performance statistics {
   PCPU core busy (current frequency): 65 %
   PCPU core busy (maximum frequency): 65 %
   APERF/MPERF ratio: -1 %
   Halted time: 172642150099 usec
}
PCPU performance statistics {
   PCPU core busy (current frequency): 55 %
   PCPU core busy (maximum frequency): 55 %
   APERF/MPERF ratio: -1 %
   Halted time: 185952136508 usec
}
PCPU performance statistics {
   PCPU core busy (current frequency): 100 %
   PCPU core busy (maximum frequency): 100 %
   APERF/MPERF ratio: -1 %
   Halted time: 172496627680 usec
}
PCPU performance statistics {
   PCPU core busy (current frequency): 100 %
   PCPU core busy (maximum frequency): 100 %
   APERF/MPERF ratio: -1 %
   Halted time: 185168370294 usec
}
PCPU performance statistics {
   PCPU core busy (current frequency): 100 %
   PCPU core busy (maximum frequency): 100 %
   APERF/MPERF ratio: -1 %
   Halted time: 174843857000 usec
}
PCPU performance statistics {
   PCPU core busy (current frequency): 100 %
   PCPU core busy (maximum frequency): 100 %
   APERF/MPERF ratio: -1 %
   Halted time: 188132157292 usec
}
PCPU performance statistics {
   PCPU core busy (current frequency): 32 %
   PCPU core busy (maximum frequency): 32 %
   APERF/MPERF ratio: -1 %
   Halted time: 174204368068 usec
}
PCPU performance statistics {
   PCPU core busy (current frequency): 63 %
   PCPU core busy (maximum frequency): 63 %
   APERF/MPERF ratio: -1 %
   Halted time: 185497348425 usec
}
PCPU performance statistics {
   PCPU core busy (current frequency): 43 %
   PCPU core busy (maximum frequency): 43 %
   APERF/MPERF ratio: -1 %
   Halted time: 172301626490 usec
}
PCPU performance statistics {
   PCPU core busy (current frequency): 44 %
   PCPU core busy (maximum frequency): 44 %
   APERF/MPERF ratio: -1 %
   Halted time: 185424645378 usec
}
PCPU performance statistics {
   PCPU core busy (current frequency): 40 %
   PCPU core busy (maximum frequency): 40 %
   APERF/MPERF ratio: -1 %
   Halted time: 172333434508 usec
}
PCPU performance statistics {
   PCPU core busy (current frequency): 41 %
   PCPU core busy (maximum frequency): 41 %
   APERF/MPERF ratio: -1 %
   Halted time: 184481550403 usec
}
```

If you were looking for an average CPU usage percentage across all the cores, I haven't found that directly yet but you could compute it:

```
[root@server:~] vsish -e get $(printf 'power/pcpu/%sperf ' $(vsish -e ls power/pcpu)) | awk '/current/ {cpus+=1;total+=$6} END {print total/cpus "%"}'
78.125%
```

I've been wanting to know this too and I didn't know about the `vsish` command so thanks for pointing it out.

Answer (score 1):

> However, I can't find a command for CPU usage. There isn't a top command or ...

There is a top command but it is "esxtop".  See https://docs.vmware.com/en/VMware-vSphere/7.0/com.vmware.vsphere.monitoring.doc/GUID-D89E8267-C74A-496F-B58E-19672CAB5A53.html for the latest documentation.  Note that although this is documentation for ESXi 7.0 esxtop has been around for over a decade so you should be able to use in ESXi 6.7.